# Image appearing before fade in

Tags: jquery, css, fadein, css-animations

Im trying to use some standard jQuery and CSS to get an image to fade in, but after fiddling with the opacity it seems as though if I set opacity to 0 in css, then the image will reappear during the animation, then disappear again once its finished. Any tips?

here is the code:

jQuery

```
<script>
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $("#me").each(function(){
    var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;
    var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (imagePos < topOfWindow+650) {
            $(this).addClass("fadeIn");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

CSS

```
@keyframes fadeIn {
    0% {
        transform: scale(0);
        opacity: 0.0;       
    }
    60% {
        transform: scale(1.1);  
    }
    80% {
        transform: scale(0.9);
        opacity: 1; 
    }   
    100% {
        transform: scale(1);
        opacity: 1; 
    }       
}
```

Comment: could you share the css for `.fadeIn` class has well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can proceed:

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/hutujuco/2/edit)

**CSS**

```
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0);
        opacity: 0.0;       
    }
    60% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);  
    }
    80% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
        opacity: 1; 
    }   
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        opacity: 0; 
    }       
}
@keyframes fadeIn {
    0% {
        transform: scale(0);
        opacity: 0.0;       
    }
    60% {
        transform: scale(1.1);  
    }
    80% {
        transform: scale(0.9);
        opacity: 1; 
    }   
    100% {
        transform: scale(1);
        opacity: 0; 
    }       
}

.fadeIn {
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 3s;
          animation: fadeIn 3s;
}

.me {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<button id="toggle-button">Toggle</button>
<div id="me" class="me"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#toggle-button').click(function () {
  var el = document.getElementById('me');
  el.classList.add('fadeIn');
  $(el).bind('webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend',   
    function(e) {
    this.classList.remove('fadeIn');
  });
});
```